Need help identifying an older book series
My husband and I read this series in the early 90s (pretty sure it's not Runeworlds). There were different worlds or maybe different levels to the same world. I feel like the covers almost has the worlds stacked on it. There was definitely magic involved. Possible runes.

Can you provide any more details?  Pretty much anything could help.  That could be anything from PJ Farmer's 'World of Tiers' to Weis' Death Gate series.  I'd lean toward the Weis books, but if you can remember any details it could help confirm.  Anything works; names, plot elements, even the primary colors of the cover.

Welcome Lori. Please take our [tour] and refer to the [help]. Your question  could describe half the fantasy books ever written. Please read this story-identification checklist and see if it helps you remember any more details. You should then [edit] the question to add them.

My best guess is Margaret Weis and Tracy Hickman's 'Death Gate' cycle.  It has 4 worlds, connected via gates, the Labyrinth and a bit more.  Both the Sartans and the Patryn use runic magic; sung / dance, or inscribed for their magic / to manipulate the waves of probability.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Death_Gate_Cycle

And the cover with the worlds stacked on top of each other?

@Valorum -- No idea; hence my request for more info... I dunno all the covers, tho, so it's possible one or more (including any Omnibus editions) might.

This feels like it could be one of the Mode series by Piers Anthony, the first three of which were published in between 1991 and 1994. These three novels are Virtual Mode, Fractal Mode and Chaos Mode. A fourth novel in the series, DoOon Mode was published in 2001.
In this series, the Mode is the universe, and has different realities connected by a 3-D plane that cuts across realities. I think these realities are more like different planets connected by the plane, rather than stacked worlds.
People can access the different realities by becoming an "anchor" using their mind to do so. Once a person is an anchor they can travel freely across the modes, but can only take objects with them that they are touching. Some of the realities use magic instead of, or alongside, technology, and some are inhabited by odd creatures such as unicorns, telepathic animals, giants etc.
The covers for the series can be found at ISFDB, but I've put them below too:
Virtual Mode:


Fractal mode


Chaos Mode


None of these look particularly like your description of worlds stacked on each-other.
